# getting error while RETURN two statement - sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GetExpenseDetails](@EmpID nvarchar(50))    
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS    
BEGIN    
   DECLARE @ExpAmount nvarchar(MAX)
   DECLARE @ExpName nvarchar(MAX)    

   IF (@EmpID <> '')    
   BEGIN    
      SELECT distinct 
         @ExpAmount = SE.ExpenseAmount, @ExpName = ME.ExpenseName
      FROM 
         tbl_admin_supplierempexpense SE, tbl_master_expense ME
      WHERE 
         SE.EmpID = @EmpID 
         AND SE.ExpenseName = ME.ExpenseID 
         AND SE.Status = 'P'  

   END    

   RETURN @ExpAmount,@ExpName   

END
```

ERROR : Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: What is this all about? Please align the code and state your problem clearly.

Comment: Use table function and return table . insert both columns in the table

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: ya i agree with you marc.. im not using as like this into my program.. it's just for testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return `more than 1` values from a FUNCTION. If you want multiple values, create a table-valued function.

See it here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx , example included

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [owner].[UDF_GetExpenseDetails](@EmpID nvarchar(50)) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
      RETURN
      (
      SELECT <column1, column2>
      FROM <table>
      WHERE <condition>   
);
```

Comment: ya this is ok !! i want to use this function in select query, thats y im returing this as varchar..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GetExpenseDetails](@EmpID nvarchar(50))    
        RETURNS @table( @ExpAmount money,@ExpName varchar(100)) 
        As 
        begin

        IF (@EmpID <> '')    
        BEGIN    
           insert into @ExpAmount 
           SELECT distinct SE.ExpenseAmount,ME.ExpenseName
           from tbl_admin_supplierempexpense SE, tbl_master_expense ME
           where SE.EmpID = @EmpID and SE.ExpenseName=ME.ExpenseID and SE.Status='P'  

        END    

  return

  END
```